# A notification on posts waiting for review and there are not posts waiting for review

Tags: support

This is how my profile looks like

[image]

There are 15 posts waiting for review. But when I go to review part, there is nothing but emptiness.

What does this notification mean? Am I on the wrong page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notification means that there are 15 tasks that have not yet been completely reviewed.

They may be tasks that you previously reviewed, or tasks that you're ineligible to review (for instance, your own posts) or simply tasks that you skipped.

As a user with [access to moderation tools](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), the site trusts you with a great deal of information that is inaccessible to other users, this count among them.

Under normal circumstances, you don't need to worry about it. Check on /review when it changes, but don't be concerned if it's a little bit higher than what you see.

But if you see it start to rise precipitously, you may wish to speak up: a site that doesn't have enough engaged users to keep an eye on moderation and review tasks is a site that is vulnerable; do what you can to get more of your peers involved.

Comment: Hm I skipped a few, but not 15. Also I did not post a new question for the last 3 weeks at least. And this appeared this morning. I never saw this before. It's also odd that I see zeros to all categories (see image). Still odd if you ask me. PS. I will take your words into account

Comment: We just turned this on last night - it replaces the functionality that previously notified folks of the number of pending moderator flags. Most of the time, review tasks are more important than flags (especially since most flags have now been moved into review).

Comment: That's what I wanted to hear and you did not mention. It's a new feature :).

Comment: Hey, are these notification SE global (as feature) or logic is bound to each community site (like Freelancing)? Because, at some point I see 20+ new notifications which I open and only see that a few of them are available. And I have not been skipping any post for months. Then again toga, I see only 4 notifs hidden for me. I guess these are the ones I skipped at some point.